# FPDF font directory / read-only on XP

Tags: fonts, windows-xp, fpdf

I'm developing a php/codeIgniter application that includes the fpdf library. I'm developing on an XP machine, but releasing to various OSs. When releasing, the application is zipped, then unzipped on the release machines. I was having problems deleting the test directories on the release machines and worked the problem down to file permissions on the fpdf/font folder.

On my XP machine, I noticed the fpdf/font folder is read-only, thus causing the subsequent problems when zipped and un-zipped. However, I'm unable to change the read-only attribute on the fpdf/font folder (either through windows explorer or directly with the attrib dos command).

The simple solution to to create another directory, copy the files over, delete the orignial font direct, rename the new directory. I'm just curious why the original directory can't be changed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to be the owner of the directory to be able to change permissions. If you are an administrator, you should be able to seize this via the security tab under right click->properties.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I'm not seeing a way to change ownership under the security tab (I'm an admin on XP Pro SP3, no windows firewall). I did try sharing it with full access on the LAN, but still couldn't change permissions.

Comment: I only have Win 7 to test on but it hasn't changed in many versions of windows. Try clicking the "advanced" button of the security tab. The window that comes up should have an "owner" tab